# How I can store some specific data in flutter like tokens or username

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I want to know how can I store some specific data in the localstorage of flutter app for example tokens or username

So I made some searches and found some dependencies and other techniques using sqlite but I want to know which are the more convenient way
Thank you

Comment: you can use shared_preferences package which i use in my all projects https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: Use [Flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage). It is alternate to shared preference.

Comment: Thank you , but the shared preferences is persistent and secure ?

Comment: it persistent not sure about secuirty

Comment: I would recommend Hive, https://pub.dev/packages/hive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flutter_secure_storage is the solution, eg:

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

final storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

//button >> onPressed
void _onLoginButton() async{
    
    //do login logic here
    
    //store datas
    await storage.write(key: 'token', value: 'token-value');
    await storage.write(key: 'username', value: 'username');
}

//eg: to get the value
String token = (await storage.read(key: 'token')) ?? '';
//or, using nullable var
String? token = await storage.read(key: 'token');
```